# Signals in C while using switchcontext

Tags: c, signals

I've tried to implement a user-level thread library, using `makecontext()`, `swapcontext()` and `getcontext()` functions. I've read that a good practice is to use signals for schedule function (with a cyclic timer), but while a new thread is adding, block signals.

My problem is that: I can implement function to block signals, but it does not work when I use context switching.

```
void initSignals()
{
    printf("initSignals\n");
    act.sa_handler = schedule;
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &act, &oact);
}


void blockSignals()
{
    printf("blockSignals\n");
    //sigset_t sig_mask;
    sigemptyset(&sig_mask);
    sigaddset(&sig_mask, SIGALRM);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sig_mask, NULL);
}

void unblockSignals()
{
    printf("unblockSignals\n");
    //sigset_t sig_mask;
    sigemptyset(&sig_mask);
    sigaddset(&sig_mask, SIGALRM);
    sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &sig_mask, NULL);
    runTimer();
}
```

About `sigset_t sig mask` now it is global, but I tried to set it like a local variable too. 
Moreover I tried to use another signals `SIGPROF, SIGVTALRM`, because my cyclic timer looks like:

```
void runTimer()
{
    printf("runTimer\n");
    it.it_interval.tv_sec = 1;
    it.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
    it.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
    it.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &it, NULL);
}
```

And itimer allow to use this 3 types of alarm...

So the question is: how to block signals while code is using context switching functions? Is it possible? Maybe another functions exist which can do that?

I thought that signals are being used for all processes, so I was surprised that it is not working...

Comment: Usually user space threads are *cooperative*, only switching when the current thread says it's okay to by calling a yield function or other potentially blocking function. See the old [GNU Pth](https://www.gnu.org/software/pth/) library for an example.